# Representing row vector as a line plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Let's say I have a row vector with the shape (1, 100). Call it `row`.

I want to display its values in a line plot. The x-axis displays the vector indices. The y-axis displays the values at the corresponding indices. How would you do it in `matplotlib`?

**EDIT:**

Here is what I have tried:

```
indices = [n for n in range(100)]
values = list(row[:, :100])
pyplot.plot(indices, values)
```

Comment: Please post the code you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array `indices` is not necessary.
The `values` array syntax is unclear... and an error in python, unless you are using `numpy`.

The following will plot an array of random values, with indices as `x` and the random numbers stored in `values` as `y`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

# indices = [n for n in range(100)]
values = [random.random() for _ in range(100)]
plt.plot(values)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    indices = range(100) # already returns a list, no need to iterate again
    values = # insert 1d vector here, what you seem to use is multi-dim
    plt.plot(indices, values)
    plt.show()
```